# Showing input of user in label when corresponding item is selected in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working on a school project and am facing a problem with my book catalog program. Users can upload information about books in textboxes, and when they add the book, it should be placed in a combobox. When selecting a book in the combobox, the corresponding labels should display information about that book.

Currently, I can upload a book and it shows the information about the just-uploaded book in the labels. However, when I select a different book from the combobox, the information in the labels does not change. I also don't know how I can retrieve the information for a specific book after it is added to the combobox.

I am using Windows Forms App (.Net Framework).

```
public void BoekenComboBox_SelectedItemChanged()
{
  string boek = boekenComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
  string titel = titelTextBox.Text.ToString();
  titelInvoerLabel.Text = Boek.titel;
  schrijverInvoerLabel.Text = ((Boek)boekenComboBox.SelectedItem).schrijver;
}

public void toevoegenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Boek nieuwBoek = new Boek();
  nieuwBoek.titel = titelTextBox.Text;
  nieuwBoek.schrijver = schrijverTextBox.Text;
  nieuwBoek.uitgever = uitgeverTextBox.Text;
  nieuwBoek.aantalbladzijdes = int.Parse(aantalbladzijdesTextBox.Text);
  nieuwBoek.status = statusTextBox.Text;
  nieuwBoek.afbeelding = afbeeldingTextBox.Text;
  boekenComboBox.Items.Add(nieuwBoek);
}
```

Boek.cs

```
namespace Boekencatalogus
{ 
  class Boek
  {
    public string titel { get; set; }
    public string schrijver { get; set; }
    public string uitgever { get; set; }
    public int aantalbladzijdes { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string afbeelding;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's important to give us some details about which framework you are using: WPF, WinForms or other. Please provide a minimal reproducibile code example

Comment: You're not doing anything with `boek` and `titel`.